# AndroidStudio import SVG with ERROR@ <mask> is not supported

Tags: android-studio, svg, vector, ide, android-vectordrawable

I got message `"ERROR@ <mask> is not supported"` when try to import SVG using

```
 Android Studio 3.0.1
Build #AI-171.4443003, built on November 10, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b08 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.6
```

Anyway to import SVG and make them show correctly?

Comment: remove the mask elements and the mask attributes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Flattern image in [Sketch](https://www.sketchapp.com/) and use [this site](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) to convert SVG to xml for Android

**Solution 2**

I use nonZero instead of evenOdd and open it in Sketch to reverse Order after reverse it will change pathData and remove android:fillType and everything work fine on Android 21+.

**Solution 3**

PNG

TLDR

After some research I found that there are two fill-rule property methods for Vector graphics, SVGs, the “evenodd” vs “nonzero”

I opened the SVG icon in Sketch and inspected the hole at the top of the icon. As expected it uses fill-rule:evenodd property. Now I have to change the fill-rule to use “nonzero” property. How? Select the path. In the right side, there is a settings icon at the “Fills” property. Click it and choose “non-zero”.

From the main menu, choose Layer → Paths → Reverse Order. I got the hole back at the top of the icon and got the hole in the app, too.

[For more detail](https://medium.com/thoughts-overflow/the-mystery-of-the-disappearing-holes-a-gripping-tale-of-using-svg-in-android-442f6035a452)

Comment: where is the link for Solution 2?

Comment: I ask designer to Flattern image by using Sketch and sometimes its work

Comment: Link is deprecated and takes you to studio tool instead so this is no longer the solution.

Answer (score 7):

Tool 1) is ShapeShifter https://shapeshifter.design

Tool 2) is https://svg2vector.com

Try this tool https://svg2vector.com on this case.
When using Android Vector Asset Studio, you may encounter these errors:

```
Missing "viewBox" in <svg> element
<animate> is not supported
<animateColor> is not supported
<animateMotion> is not supported
<animateTransform> is not supported
<mpath> is not supported
<set> is not supported
<a> is not supported
<defs> is not supported
<glyph> is not supported
<marker> is not supported
<mask> is not supported
<missing-glyph> is not supported
<pattern> is not supported
<switch> is not supported
<symbol> is not supported
<feBlend> is not supported
<feColorMatrix> is not supported
<feComponentTransfer> is not supported
<feComposite> is not supported
<feConvolveMatrix> is not supported
<feDiffuseLighting> is not supported
<feDisplacementMap> is not supported
<feFlood> is not supported
<feFuncA> is not supported
<feFuncB> is not supported
<feFuncG> is not supported
<feFuncR> is not supported
<feGaussianBlur> is not supported
<feImage> is not supported
<feMerge> is not supported
<feMergeNode> is not supported
<feMorphology> is not supported
<feOffset> is not supported
<feSpecularLighting> is not supported
<feTile> is not supported
<feTurbulence> is not supported
<font> is not supported
<font-face> is not supported
<font-face-format> is not supported
<font-face-name> is not supported
<font-face-src> is not supported
<font-face-uri> is not supported
<hkern> is not supported
<vkern> is not supported
<linearGradient> is not supported
<radialGradient> is not supported
<stop> is not supported
<ellipse> is not supported
<polyline> is not supported
<text> is not supported
<use> is not supported
<feDistantLight> is not supported
<fePointLight> is not supported
<feSpotLight> is not supported
<altGlyph> is not supported
<altGlyphDef> is not supported
<altGlyphItem> is not supported
<glyphRef> is not supported
<textPath> is not supported
<tref> is not supported
<tspan> is not supported
<clipPath> is not supported
<color-profile> is not supported
<cursor> is not supported
<filter> is not supported
<foreignObject> is not supported
<script> is not supported
<view> is not supported
```

Comment: What causes these errors in Android Studio?

Answer (score 6):

If all you have is the .svg file, you can manipulate the .svg markup by hand to remove the mask and apply a fill inline.

If you're working with a designer, you can ask them to take the icon and remove whatever is inside the mask and apply a fill to the icon instead. Then have the designer export the .svg file and retry the import into Android Studio.

When the asset you're trying to import is exported from a designer software like Sketch or other, AND the icon is a mask (as opposed to a fill) it will export with that  tag. Android Studio only accepts .svg's with fills (this is not a problem with iOS)

Answer (score 6):

1. Open the SVG file and remove the `mask` element. You can keep the `use` element.
2. Import
3. Open imported file
4. Remove the last element that has`fillType="evenOdd"`
5. Update the color on the `android:fillType="nonZero"` element

This depends of course on how the designer exports the asset but editing paths like this will most always get you where you want.

Comment: Almost, but the element was circular and ended up squared

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was the result of a symbol override in Sketch which is a known technique which enables you to easily change a symbol's color. It requires you to use a (color) symbol inside a symbol (nested symbols) as a mask. This is the mask that was causing issues.

My solution was simply to create an export version of the original symbol where I delete the mask.