# android studio SVG File Import Getting ERROR @ line 8: Unsupported color format "rgba(0,0,0,0)"

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable, adaptive-icon

Recently i started to create adaptive icons for android app

SVG File Import for ic_launcher_background.xml successfully, but for ic_launcher_foreground.xml am getting error below like this

1. ERROR @ line 8: Unsupported color format "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
2. ERROR @ line 9:  is not supported

**Note: i can't able to post the full code so i remove the path data**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:width="108dp"
    android:height="108dp"
    android:viewportWidth="108"
    android:viewportHeight="108">
    <group>
        <clip-path android:pathData="M0 0H108V108H0V0Z" />
        <path
            android:fillColor="#00000000"
            android:pathData="M0 0H108V108H0V0Z" />
        <group
            android:translateX="54.5"
            android:translateY="52.5">
            <path
                android:fillColor="#FFE600"
                android:pathData="M-16.06429 -19.14453L-16.06429 -1.557617L-12.76498 -1.217773L-12.76498 0L-23.44173 0L-23.44173 -1.217773L-20.15658 -1.557617L-20.15658 -15.87354L-23.42757 -14.79736L-23.42757 -16.00098L-18.07504 -19.14453L-16.06429 -19.14453ZM2.131508 -9.572266L2.131508 -9.572266Q2.131508 0.2832031 -4.098961 0.2832031L-4.098961 0.2832031Q-7.100914 0.2832031 -8.630211 -2.237305Q-10.15951 -4.757813 -10.15951 -9.572266L-10.15951 -9.572266Q-10.15951 -14.2876 -8.630211 -16.78687Q-7.100914 -19.28613 -3.98568 -19.28613L-3.98568 -19.28613Q-0.9837266 -19.28613 0.5738906 -16.81519Q2.131508 -14.34424 2.131508 -9.572266ZM-2.017418 -9.572266L-2.017418 -9.572266Q-2.017418 -13.99023 -2.513023 -15.9231Q-3.008629 -17.85596 -4.070641 -17.85596L-4.070641 -17.85596Q-5.118492 -17.85596 -5.564537 -15.98682Q-6.010582 -14.11768 -6.010582 -9.572266L-6.010582 -9.572266Q-6.010582 -4.956055 -5.557457 -3.044434Q-5.104332 -1.132813 -4.070641 -1.132813L-4.070641 -1.132813Q-3.022789 -1.132813 -2.520104 -3.093994Q-2.017418 -5.055176 -2.017418 -9.572266ZM16.33414 -14.31592L16.33414 -14.31592Q16.33414 -12.7583 15.5695 -11.66089Q14.80485 -10.56348 13.41715 -10.06787L13.41715 -10.06787Q15.04557 -9.458984 15.90934 -8.18457Q16.77311 -6.910156 16.77311 -5.125977L16.77311 -5.125977Q16.77311 -2.435547 15.22257 -1.076172Q13.67204 0.2832031 10.40104 0.2832031L10.40104 0.2832031Q4.198891 0.2832031 4.198891 -5.125977L4.198891 -5.125977Q4.198891 -6.938477 5.07682 -8.212891Q5.95475 -9.487305 7.512367 -10.06787L7.512367 -10.06787Q6.138832 -10.5918 5.388344 -11.68213Q4.637855 -12.77246 4.637855 -14.3584L4.637855 -14.3584Q4.637855 -16.68066 6.174232 -17.9834Q7.710609 -19.28613 10.51432 -19.28613L10.51432 -19.28613Q13.26139 -19.28613 14.79777 -17.96216Q16.33414 -16.63818 16.33414 -14.31592ZM12.75163 -5.125977L12.75163 -5.125977Q12.75163 -7.306641 12.18522 -8.297852Q11.61881 -9.289063 10.40104 -9.289063L10.40104 -9.289063Q9.239906 -9.289063 8.730141 -8.326172Q8.220375 -7.363281 8.220375 -5.125977L8.220375 -5.125977Q8.220375 -2.931152 8.737221 -2.039063Q9.254066 -1.146973 10.40104 -1.146973L10.40104 -1.146973Q11.61881 -1.146973 12.18522 -2.081543Q12.75163 -3.016113 12.75163 -5.125977ZM12.31266 -14.31592L12.31266 -14.31592Q12.31266 -16.1709 11.84538 -17.01343Q11.37809 -17.85596 10.42936 -17.85596L10.42936 -17.85596Q9.523109 -17.85596 9.091225 -17.02051Q8.65934 -16.18506 8.65934 -14.31592L8.65934 -14.31592Q8.65934 -12.39014 9.084145 -11.59717Q9.508949 -10.8042 10.42936 -10.8042L10.42936 -10.8042Q11.40641 -10.8042 11.85954 -11.61841Q12.31266 -12.43262 12.31266 -14.31592Z"
                android:strokeWidth="0.5"
                android:strokeColor="#DC8B00" />
        </group>
        <group
            android:translateX="54.5"
            android:translateY="70.5">
            <path
                android:fillColor="#FFE600"
                android:pathData="M-11.78146 -3.598633L-11.78146 -3.598633Q-11.78146 -5.15625 -12.3508 -5.884033Q-12.92014 -6.611816 -14.20383 -6.611816L-14.20383 -6.611816L-14.60129 -6.611816L-14.60129 -0.6123047Q-14.08566 -0.5693359 -13.66672 -0.5693359L-13.66672 -0.5693359Q-12.96848 -0.5693359 -12.56296 -0.8701172Q-12.15744 -1.170898 -11.96945 -1.812744Q-11.78146 -2.45459 -11.78146 -3.598633ZM-17.21164 -7.202637L-13.79025 -7.202637Q-11.85129 -7.202637 -10.92478 -6.324463Q-9.998262 -5.446289 -9.998262 -3.641602L-9.998262 -3.641602Q-9.998262 -1.788574 -10.88449 -0.8835449Q-11.77072 0.02148438 -13.56467 0.02148438L-13.56467 0.02148438L-15.97629 0L-17.21164 0L-17.21164 -0.3920898L-16.28781 -0.5371094L-16.28781 -6.670898L-17.21164 -6.810547L-17.21164 -7.202637ZM-7.119355 -7.632324L-7.119355 -5.446289Q-7.119355 -5.091797 -7.151582 -4.608398L-7.151582 -4.608398L-6.780977 -4.796387Q-6.018281 -5.183105 -5.411348 -5.183105L-5.411348 -5.183105Q-4.014863 -5.183105 -4.014863 -3.695313L-4.014863 -3.695313L-4.014863 -0.4833984L-3.50998 -0.3544922L-3.50998 0L-6.018281 0L-6.018281 -0.3544922L-5.567109 -0.4833984L-5.567109 -3.48584Q-5.567109 -3.937012 -5.757783 -4.189453Q-5.948457 -4.441895 -6.302949 -4.441895L-6.302949 -4.441895Q-6.711152 -4.441895 -7.119355 -4.259277L-7.119355 -4.259277L-7.119355 -0.4833984L-6.657441 -0.3544922L-6.657441 0L-9.165742 0L-9.165742 -0.3544922L-8.671602 -0.4833984L-8.671602 -7.148926L-9.187227 -7.277832L-9.187227 -7.632324L-7.119355 -7.632324ZM-1.00168 -5.048828L-1.00168 -0.4833984L-0.448457 -0.3544922L-0.448457 0L-3.101777 0L-3.101777 -0.3544922L-2.553926 -0.4833984L-2.553926 -4.56543L-3.069551 -4.694336L-3.069551 -5.048828L-1.00168 -5.048828ZM-2.607637 -6.810547L-2.607637 -6.810547Q-2.607637 -7.159668 -2.363252 -7.395996Q-2.118867 -7.632324 -1.780488 -7.632324L-1.780488 -7.632324Q-1.436738 -7.632324 -1.197725 -7.393311Q-0.9587109 -7.154297 -0.9587109 -6.810547L-0.9587109 -6.810547Q-0.9587109 -6.472168 -1.195039 -6.227783Q-1.431367 -5.983398 -1.780488 -5.983398L-1.780488 -5.983398Q-2.124238 -5.983398 -2.365938 -6.222412Q-2.607637 -6.461426 -2.607637 -6.810547ZM4.847441 -4.586914L2.82791 0.1074219L2.178008 0.1074219L0.06716797 -4.56543L-0.2873242 -4.694336L-0.2873242 -5.048828L2.296172 -5.048828L2.296172 -4.694336L1.694609 -4.554688L2.989043 -1.675781L4.15457 -4.56543L3.56375 -4.694336L3.56375 -5.048828L5.212676 -5.048828L5.212676 -4.694336L4.847441 -4.586914ZM7.694121 0.1557617L7.694121 0.1557617L5.67459 -4.56543L5.320098 -4.694336L5.320098 -5.048828L7.903594 -5.048828L7.903594 -4.694336L7.302031 -4.554688L8.489043 -1.761719L9.547148 -4.56543L8.956328 -4.694336L8.956328 -5.048828L10.60525 -5.048828L10.60525 -4.694336L10.24002 -4.586914L8.247344 0.3168945Q7.903594 1.192383 7.645781 1.587158Q7.387969 1.981934 7.07376 2.177979Q6.759551 2.374023 6.356719 2.374023L6.356719 2.374023Q5.92166 2.374023 5.470488 2.271973L5.470488 2.271973L5.470488 0.972168L5.792754 0.972168L6.023711 1.648926Q6.179473 1.772461 6.421172 1.772461L6.421172 1.772461Q6.625273 1.772461 6.781035 1.675781Q6.936797 1.579102 7.07376 1.396484Q7.210723 1.213867 7.334258 0.947998Q7.457793 0.6821289 7.694121 0.1557617ZM13.64529 -5.161621L13.64529 -5.161621Q15.54129 -5.161621 15.54129 -3.765137L15.54129 -3.765137L15.54129 -0.4833984L16.04617 -0.3544922L16.04617 0L14.18777 0L14.06961 -0.3867188Q13.65066 -0.1020508 13.31229 0.002685547Q12.97391 0.1074219 12.63016 0.1074219L12.63016 0.1074219Q11.06717 0.1074219 11.06717 -1.396484L11.06717 -1.396484Q11.06717 -1.96582 11.29812 -2.306885Q11.52908 -2.647949 11.96414 -2.811768Q12.3992 -2.975586 13.33377 -2.99707L13.33377 -2.99707L13.98904 -3.013184L13.98904 -3.749023Q13.98904 -4.662109 13.24246 -4.662109L13.24246 -4.662109Q12.79129 -4.662109 12.2327 -4.382813L12.2327 -4.382813L12.02859 -3.754395L11.6741 -3.754395L11.6741 -4.973633Q12.48514 -5.097168 12.86648 -5.129395Q13.24783 -5.161621 13.64529 -5.161621ZM13.98904 -0.7304688L13.98904 -2.535156L13.53787 -2.519043Q13.01687 -2.497559 12.81546 -2.245117Q12.61404 -1.992676 12.61404 -1.428711L12.61404 -1.428711Q12.61404 -0.972168 12.77518 -0.7573242Q12.93631 -0.5424805 13.19412 -0.5424805L13.19412 -0.5424805Q13.55936 -0.5424805 13.98904 -0.7304688L13.98904 -0.7304688Z"
                android:strokeWidth="0.5"
                android:strokeColor="#DC8B00" />
            <path
                android:fillColor="#FFE600"
                android:pathData="M-14.81646 7.401367L-14.81646 7.401367Q-14.81646 5.84375 -15.3858 5.115967Q-15.95514 4.388184 -17.23883 4.388184L-17.23883 4.388184L-17.63629 4.388184L-17.63629 10.3877Q-17.12066 10.43066 -16.70172 10.43066L-16.70172 10.43066Q-16.00348 10.43066 -15.59796 10.12988Q-15.19244 9.829102 -15.00445 9.187256Q-14.81646 8.54541 -14.81646 7.401367ZM-20.24664 3.797363L-16.82525 3.797363Q-14.88629 3.797363 -13.95978 4.675537Q-13.03326 5.553711 -13.03326 7.358398L-13.03326 7.358398Q-13.03326 9.211426 -13.91949 10.11646Q-14.80572 11.02148 -16.59967 11.02148L-16.59967 11.02148L-19.01129 11L-20.24664 11L-20.24664 10.60791L-19.32281 10.46289L-19.32281 4.329102L-20.24664 4.189453L-20.24664 3.797363ZM-9.842832 5.827637L-9.842832 5.827637Q-8.816953 5.827637 -8.357725 6.375488Q-7.898496 6.92334 -7.898496 8.078125L-7.898496 8.078125L-7.898496 8.518555L-10.54645 8.518555L-10.54645 8.604492Q-10.54645 9.404785 -10.41754 9.743164Q-10.28863 10.08154 -9.998594 10.25879Q-9.708555 10.43604 -9.203672 10.43604L-9.203672 10.43604Q-8.731016 10.43604 -8.011289 10.28027L-8.011289 10.28027L-8.011289 10.69385Q-8.306699 10.87109 -8.77667 10.98657Q-9.246641 11.10205 -9.692441 11.10205L-9.692441 11.10205Q-10.93316 11.10205 -11.52667 10.45483Q-12.12018 9.807617 -12.12018 8.44873L-12.12018 8.44873Q-12.12018 7.127441 -11.55353 6.477539Q-10.98688 5.827637 -9.842832 5.827637ZM-9.901914 6.370117L-9.901914 6.370117Q-10.22418 6.370117 -10.38263 6.719238Q-10.54107 7.068359 -10.54107 7.95459L-10.54107 7.95459L-9.370176 7.95459Q-9.370176 7.234863 -9.418516 6.942139Q-9.466855 6.649414 -9.582334 6.509766Q-9.697813 6.370117 -9.901914 6.370117ZM-3.601621 9.399414L-3.601621 9.399414Q-3.601621 10.24268 -4.119932 10.67505Q-4.638242 11.10742 -5.626523 11.10742L-5.626523 11.10742Q-6.034727 11.10742 -6.526182 11.0188Q-7.017637 10.93018 -7.270078 10.8335L-7.270078 10.8335L-7.270078 9.458496L-6.915586 9.458496L-6.711484 10.16748Q-6.523496 10.35547 -6.217344 10.48169Q-5.911191 10.60791 -5.594297 10.60791L-5.594297 10.60791Q-5.127012 10.60791 -4.89874 10.40649Q-4.670469 10.20508 -4.670469 9.893555L-4.670469 9.893555Q-4.670469 9.598145 -4.890684 9.420898Q-5.110898 9.243652 -5.852109 9.012695L-5.852109 9.012695Q-6.630918 8.770996 -6.955869 8.352051Q-7.28082 7.933105 -7.28082 7.320801L-7.28082 7.320801Q-7.28082 6.633301 -6.770566 6.225098Q-6.260313 5.816895 -5.454648 5.816895L-5.454648 5.816895Q-4.901426 5.816895 -3.966855 5.972656L-3.966855 5.972656L-3.966855 7.26709L-4.321348 7.26709L-4.493223 6.67627Q-4.648984 6.520508 -4.930967 6.421143Q-5.212949 6.321777 -5.465391 6.321777L-5.465391 6.321777Q-5.852109 6.321777 -6.037412 6.480225Q-6.222715 6.638672 -6.222715 6.912598L-6.222715 6.912598Q-6.222715 7.197266 -5.991758 7.379883Q-5.760801 7.5625 -5.041074 7.777344L-5.041074 7.777344Q-4.256895 8.019043 -3.929258 8.413818Q-3.601621 8.808594 -3.601621 9.399414ZM-0.9912695 3.367676L-0.9912695 5.553711Q-0.9912695 5.908203 -1.023496 6.391602L-1.023496 6.391602L-0.6528906 6.203613Q0.1098047 5.816895 0.7167383 5.816895L0.7167383 5.816895Q2.113223 5.816895 2.113223 7.304688L2.113223 7.304688L2.113223 10.5166L2.618105 10.64551L2.618105 11L0.1098047 11L0.1098047 10.64551L0.5609766 10.5166L0.5609766 7.51416Q0.5609766 7.062988 0.3703027 6.810547Q0.1796289 6.558105 -0.1748633 6.558105L-0.1748633 6.558105Q-0.5830664 6.558105 -0.9912695 6.740723L-0.9912695 6.740723L-0.9912695 10.5166L-0.5293555 10.64551L-0.5293555 11L-3.037656 11L-3.037656 10.64551L-2.543516 10.5166L-2.543516 3.851074L-3.059141 3.722168L-3.059141 3.367676L-0.9912695 3.367676ZM5.717227 5.838379L5.717227 5.838379Q7.613223 5.838379 7.613223 7.234863L7.613223 7.234863L7.613223 10.5166L8.118105 10.64551L8.118105 11L6.259707 11L6.141543 10.61328Q5.722598 10.89795 5.384219 11.00269Q5.04584 11.10742 4.70209 11.10742L4.70209 11.10742Q3.139102 11.10742 3.139102 9.603516L3.139102 9.603516Q3.139102 9.03418 3.370059 8.693115Q3.601016 8.352051 4.036074 8.188232Q4.471133 8.024414 5.405703 8.00293L5.405703 8.00293L6.060977 7.986816L6.060977 7.250977Q6.060977 6.337891 5.314395 6.337891L5.314395 6.337891Q4.863223 6.337891 4.304629 6.617188L4.304629 6.617188L4.100527 7.245605L3.746035 7.245605L3.746035 6.026367Q4.55707 5.902832 4.938418 5.870605Q5.319766 5.838379 5.717227 5.838379ZM6.060977 10.26953L6.060977 8.464844L5.609805 8.480957Q5.088809 8.502441 4.887393 8.754883Q4.685977 9.007324 4.685977 9.571289L4.685977 9.571289Q4.685977 10.02783 4.847109 10.24268Q5.008242 10.45752 5.266055 10.45752L5.266055 10.45752Q5.631289 10.45752 6.060977 10.26953L6.060977 10.26953ZM10.54047 5.951172L10.61566 6.391602L10.9809 6.203613Q11.73285 5.816895 12.32904 5.816895L12.32904 5.816895Q13.23139 5.816895 13.53217 6.472168L13.53217 6.472168Q14.63324 5.816895 15.39057 5.816895L15.39057 5.816895Q16.75482 5.816895 16.75482 7.304688L16.75482 7.304688L16.75482 10.5166L17.25971 10.64551L17.25971 11L14.75141 11L14.75141 10.64551L15.20258 10.5166L15.20258 7.51416Q15.20258 7.062988 15.02802 6.810547Q14.85346 6.558105 14.49896 6.558105L14.49896 6.558105Q14.1015 6.558105 13.63959 6.783691L13.63959 6.783691Q13.6933 7.009277 13.6933 7.304688L13.6933 7.304688L13.6933 10.5166L14.19818 10.64551L14.19818 11L11.68988 11L11.68988 10.64551L12.14105 10.5166L12.14105 7.51416Q12.14105 7.062988 11.96649 6.810547Q11.79193 6.558105 11.43744 6.558105L11.43744 6.558105Q11.08295 6.558105 10.62641 6.767578L10.62641 6.767578L10.62641 10.5166L11.08832 10.64551L11.08832 11L8.58002 11L8.58002 10.64551L9.07416 10.5166L9.07416 6.43457L8.58002 6.305664L8.58002 5.951172L10.54047 5.951172Z"
                android:strokeWidth="0.5"
                android:strokeColor="#DC8B00" />
        </group>
    </group>
</vector>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49488601/6762459

Comment: can you share your xml code?

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17940/332043) on XML/HTML formatting

Answer (score 3):

Solution is you need to fix your SVG first.

Very easy like this:

```
fill="#186bfe" fill-opacity="0.3"
```

Your case rgba(0,0,0,0). then it should be fixed

```
fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0"
```

Comment: Thanks. Talking about exact syntax, in svg file I had to replace 1) .prefix__cls-2{fill:rgba(247,248,255,.6)} by .prefix__cls-2{fill:#f7f8ff;fill-opacity:.6} and 2) style="fill:rgba(128,147,218,.18) by style="fill:#8093da;fill-opacity:.18"